# Search for treshold values based on key from three columns(or more)

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I need help with dataset that looks like this:

```
Name1   Name2   Name3   Temp    Height
Alon    Walon   Balon   105     34  ]
Alon    Walon   Balon   106     42  |
Alon    Walon   Balon   105     33  ]-- Samples of Spot: Alon-Walon-Balon
Alon    Walon   Kalon   101     11  ]
Alon    Walon   Kalon   102     32  ]-- Samples of Spot: Alon-Walon-Kalon
Alon    Talon   Balon   111     12  ]-- Samples of Spot: Alon-Talon-Balon
Alon    Talon   Calon   121     10  ]-- Samples of Spot: Alon-Talon-Calon
```

What I want to achieve?

I have samples for one point in space, this point is described with three words, in this case let's take Alon-Walon-Balon:
I want to compare each value from Temp to other value like 105 if this value is higher than 105 then save this to another column.
The same goes for Height.

How am I doing this right now?

```
df = df.groupby[['Name1','Name2','Name3','Temp','Height']].size().reset_index()
visited = ()
cntSpot = 0
overValTemp = 0
overValHeight = 0
for i in len(df):
    name1 = str(df.get_value(i,'Name1'))
    name2 = str(df.get_value(i,'Name2'))
    name3 = str(df.get_value(i,'Name3'))
    if str(name1+name2+name3) in visited:
        cntSpot+=1
        if df.get_value(i,'Temp')>105:
            overValTemp+=1
        if df.get_value(i,'Height)<13:
            overValHeight+=1
        a = str(name1+name2+name3)
        visited.update({a:cntSpot,overValemp,overValHeight})
```

Now I have set of dictionaries with information how many times every spot is over certain values.
This is the information I need, how many times case occurred for one Spot.
Where is the trick?
The csv files are more than 2GB and I need to process It incredibely fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, that uses pandas groupby and is definitely more efficient than the loop.

```
grouped = df.groupby(('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'))

count = grouped.size()
temp = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Temp']>105].shape[0])
height = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Height']<13].shape[0])

result = pd.concat([count, temp, height],
                   keys = ['Count', 'overValTemp', 'overValHeight'],
                   axis = 1)
result.index = map(lambda x: "-".join(x), result.index.tolist())
```

The result is the following:

```
                  Count  overValTemp  overValHeight
Alon-Talon-Balon      1            1              1
Alon-Talon-Calon      1            1              1
Alon-Walon-Balon      3            1              0
Alon-Walon-Kalon      2            0              1
```

Comment: Edited the answer, simplifying the code. It should be cleaner now.

Comment: Great job at explaining it to me. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it helps. Please upvote and accept the answer if this solves your problem :)

Comment: I cannot upvote now, when my reputation will be more than 15 points I will :) I'll test in a minute

Comment: I have just one question and I'm gone if you want to have like number between i have to do this like that? height = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Height']<13 & x[x['Height']>5].shape[0])

Comment: Ok i found solution. height = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Height'].isin(range(12,32))].shape[0]). Thanks again :)

Comment: I think isin is the best way to check if is in range. more generally, you can combine conditions using the boolean operators & (AND) and | (OR). Just remember to put brackets around the statements:
example  grouped.apply(lambda x: x[ (x['Height']<13) & (x['Height']>5)].shape[0])